# How to create an array of objects from an existing array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an array whose elements are in string format, like this:

```
somearray = ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"]
```

I need to create an object from this array whose variable I have declared as `var newobject = {}`. I tried this:

```
var newobject = {};
var index = 0;
somearray.forEach(function() {
    newobj = {
        name : somearray[index]
    };
    index++;
});
```

This does create an object but only consisting of the last string in the array (`somearray`)

If instead of

```
newobj = {
    name : somearray[index]
};
```

I write

```
newobj[index] = {
    name : somearray[index]
};
```

the objects are named 0,1,2. I don't want this to happen, nor do I want anything else in its place.
Isn't there any way like how we use push method for arrays?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? An object always has a key for each value.

Comment: What do you want as the keys and values of the object?

Comment: Please show us how the expected result is supposed to look (as JSON)

Comment: Expected output is [object, object, object] where each object is {name: "abc/pqr/xyz"}

Comment: `var result = somearray.map(function(str, i) { return {name: str} })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution using `Array.forEach` and `Array.push` functions:

```
var somearray = ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"], objects = [];

somearray.forEach((v) => objects.push({name: v}) );    
console.log(JSON.stringify(objects, 0, 4));
```

Or the same using `Array.map` function:

```
var somearray = ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"], objects;  
objects = somearray.map((v) => ({name: v}) );
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "abc"
    },
    {
        "name": "pqr"
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use key-value notation:

```js
var newobject = {};
var somearray = ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"] ;
somearray.forEach(function(x,i){
  newobject[i]=x;
})
console.log(newobject);
```

Comment: Why use `.map()`? You're just throwing away the resulting Array of `undefined`. Either `.forEach()` or `.reduce()` would make more sense.

Comment: @squint Are you very much worried about the thrown array? I use it because it's shorter...

Comment: yes it could have been done like `newObj = somearray.reduce((p,c,i) => (p[i] = c,p),{});`

Comment: @nicael: Are you very much worried about 4 more characters? Constructing, populating and discarding an array without using it at all is a very strange thing to do intentionally.

Comment: @nicael of course it will effect performance, your creating an array and then throwing it away for no reason. You don't get that for free.